# How to display a list sqlite database tables, except table sqlite_sequence?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Doing so

```
select name from sqlite_master where type='table'
```

but I need to display all tables except sqlite_sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the following SQL?

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name <> 'sqlite_sequence'
```